# Angular Select ng-model is null after selecting value

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem with Angular select and `ng-model`. The issue can best be described in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gp8c17m/

Basically I have a select such as:

```
<select ng-options="item.Label as item.label for item in entry.Data.Options | orderBy: label" 
ng-model="entry.Data.Value">
```

The value `entry.Data.Value` is first set to `entry.Data.Options[0]` but that does not make the select list show this value, and if I select another value in the select the `entry.Data.Value` becomes null..

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Edit: in the "real app" the `entry` value comes from a loop of values which can contain many different elements, the select being one of the types. The select is included in the real apps html using a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the thing you want: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hqJbin4Pc22cf1a6UcAd?p=preview)

```
<select class="form-control FieldHeight-1x" 
    ng-options="item.label for item in entry.Data.Options | orderBy: label" 
    ng-model="entry.Data.Value">
</select>
<button ng-click="GetValue()">
    value
</button>
<br />

{{entry.Data.Value}}
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you, was going nuts over this.. more coffe needed!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :) Oh you reminded me of my coffee!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that javascript is case sensitive

try this

```
<select 
    ng-options="item.Label as item.label for item in entry.Data.Options | 
    orderBy: label" 
    ng-model="entry.Data.Value">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="controller.selectedYear" ng-options="y for y in controller.years">
```

If selected year is 2017, but ng-options are 2015, 2016. It is not working.

```
<select ng-model="controller.selectedYear" ng-options="y for y in controller.years">
```

It is not working because we use "Year" instead of "year".